# Mysql Update with if statement

Tags: mysql, if-statement

In MySQL

```
Table1 columns Id, Foo, Bar, Choc, Blk, AB

Table2 columns ID, A, B, C
```

Im trying to update table 1 col AB with result of

```
IF( (C / ((A + B)/ 2))>1, "A...", "B..." ) from Table2 

Where T1.id =t2.id
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
UPDATE table1
JOIN Table2 on Table1.id = Table2.id
SET AB = CASE WHEN C / ((A + B)/ 2) > 1 THEN "A..." ELSE "B..." END
```