# Conditional isn't working

Tags: mysql

Spent an hour already searching and trying to get this work. Starting to hate mysql.
What am I doing wrong here?

```
UPDATE product_reward pr
  LEFT JOIN product p ON (pr.product_id = p.product_id)
  LEFT JOIN product_special ps ON (pr.product_id = ps.product_id)

SELECT CASE ps.price  
  WHEN NULL
    THEN SET pr.points = ROUND(p.price * 1);
  ELSE 
    SET pr.points = ROUND(ps.price * 1);
END;
```

I tried using normal `IF ELSE`, but apparently that only works inside of procedures.
I'm trying to set points based on normal price only if special price is `NULL`.

Comment: after having a second look, I am not getting the `p.price * 1`, you want to force a cast to integer here?

Answer (score 2):

try this or have a look into [Mysql Update with if statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5546067/mysql-update-with-if-statement)

```
UPDATE product_reward pr
  LEFT JOIN product p ON (pr.product_id = p.product_id)
  LEFT JOIN product_special ps ON (pr.product_id = ps.product_id)

SET pr.points = ROUND(COALESCE(ps.price, p.price) * 1)
```

Comment: You can simplify it further to `SET pr.points = ROUND(COALESCE(ps.price, p.price) * 1)`

Comment: very true, changed according to that